# How Do I find the Correct XPATH?

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to find the correct XPath to use with the HTML Agility Pack. I've tried multiple XPaths but all give me the -        **$exception    {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}   System.NullReferenceException**

Here are some of the XPaths I've tried.  All give me an error

```
            //*[@id="div_team-stats-per_game"]
        // html / body / div[2] / div[5] / div[4] / div[3] / div
        //*[@id="team-stats-per_game"]/tbody
```

Here is my code:

```
            HtmlWeb web1 = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc1 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc1 = web1.Load("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021.html");
        var _extractText = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"team-stats-per_game\"]").InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(_extractText);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the ability to use the LoadFromBrowser method? The method you are using currently will get the raw HTML of the document but not the dynamically loaded content.

The table you are trying to parse is loaded into the page via javascript so you would need to use the LoadFromBrowser method and wait for the element to be shown:

```
        HtmlWeb web1 = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc1 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        doc1 = web1.LoadFromBrowser("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021.html", html => {
            // Wait for the HTML element to exist
            return !html.Contains("<table id=\"team-stats-per_game\">");
        });

        var _extractText = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"team-stats-per_game\"]").InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(_extractText);
```

Comment: Ben, Thanks that fixed the issue.  How can you determine the data is loaded from Javascript?

Comment: There are a number of ways you can check this:

If you output the content of the HtmlDocument to a file and then open that file you'll see that most content is missing; meaning it is being loaded in after the page loads.

You can also use your browser to mock network conditions to have it load slowly and you'll see that those tables come in later. [Network Throttling in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#throttling)

Again the browser dev tools will let you see what content is being loaded over the network and drill down through that.